# Making controls fullscreen

Tags: c#, winforms, fullscreen

Can I make a control (in Windows Forms) go fullscreen? Could I do it with P/Invoke? I thought that a solution might be running through all of the controls in the Form, then ensuring it is a type of my control, setting the location to 0,0, putting it on top, re-sizing the control to fit the form, and then changing the form so it fills the screen. I would prefer to do it another way because this method doesn't seem to reliable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a control in particular you want to make fullscreen? Or, do you want to make the entire form fullscreen?

Comment: You have to change the form to fill the screen *first* (or maximize it), and *then* resize the control.

Comment: @seesharper: do you want the Windows sys tray be visible?

Comment: It is a particular control, but the method that I mentioned, made the form go fullscreen as well. I was hoping that there would be a way that just the control could go fullscreen, to prevent the form from being messed up. @Tigran: I would like it if the tray wasn't visible.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend maximizing the form, then docking the control as full to the form.

```
        control.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Answer (score 3):

Considering that you want to hide SysTray too, there is a solution I'm aware of and used long years ago during writing the `POS` applications. You could do something like this:

```
private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
private const int SW_SHOW = 1;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int FindWindow(string className, string windowText);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int command);

int hWnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
```

In this way the systray will be hidden.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/FullScreenDotNetApp.aspx) is a good article on subject.

But as this was a long time ago here you should check a couple of possible problems.

- Does it run on Windows 7 ?
- Does it run on Windows 64 bit versions (see `[DllImport("user32.dll")]`)  ?

Hope this helps.